# Best way to cache data on node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have Json file I need to look for specific value (file is pretty big) and I want to turn this json into array so doing so would be easier and faster.
BUT what is the best way to save this array? so I wont need to run over this json every time and it will be saved until recycle or service restart?
(node js project)

Comment: Sounds like you want a database

Comment: How much big is your file ?

Comment: @JosephYoung and saving it locally like cache?

Comment: @Abanoub about 100+ objects in

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache

Comment: Why don't you store the file in memory as a JavaScript Object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Use [Redis](https://www.mongodb.com/) **recommended**

***Pros:***

1. Access objects super fast.
2. Isolated from `node` process.

   - Will not affect heap memory.
   - Can be deployed at separated server.
   - Data persistence if your application crashed.
3. Support compression.

   - low memory consumption.

***Cons:***

1. You may face some limitations if you have nested objects, but there
   is a workaround which requires extra work to handle.

---

2) Use database **preferred** [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/),

***Pros:***

1. `Save/Load` objects easily since `MongoDB` supports JSON.
2. The same as number **2** of `Redis` pros

***Cons:***

1. You have to query every time to access objects.

---

3) Use [Files](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) **not recommended**, When your application `start/restart`, load your objects form file into global array, and when `close/shutdown` your application dump your objects from global array back into file.

***Pros:***

1. Access objects fast.

***Cons:***

1. Heap memory leakage if your objects size are Huge.
2. Data loss if your application crashed.

---

At the end it's your choice, if the speed matters choose `Redis`, if you want the easy way choose `mongoDB`. If it's not a problem losing some of your data go for `Files`. Also you can mix between number **2** and **3**.